# How to force immediate Yammer DirSync

Tags: yammer

I deleted incrementalquerycursors.config and re-started Yammer DirSync but it's still waiting for an hour to run.  I thought there was a way to force it to run immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to delete the lastvalidation file as well and restart yammer Dirsync service (not only the app) from mmc.